# A question about the performance of htmlText in TextField

Tags: apache-flex, flash, performance, cs3

I have got a performance problem about `TextField.htmlText +=msg`.And
I know that`TextField.appendText(msg)` works better than `TextField.text +=msg`.So I wonder if there's some method better than `TextField.htmlText +=msg`?Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Spawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't benchmarked it, but what I normally do is this:

```
var str:String = "bla bla";

for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
    str += " foo";
}

myTextfield.htmlText = str;
```

However, it's likely not that much of a boost unless you're doing large amounts of text and/or iterations.

Comment: There's a more than 100 percent increased performance.Nice solution:)

Comment: It's also the case that *.htmlText += str* is slower than *.appendText(str)*

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate your text in a variable before assigning it to the htmlText property of any control. Every time you change that property you are calling all the lifecycle display methods like commitProperties, measure, and updateDisplayList, all of which take time to render.

Comment: Thanks,and happy to see native language!